# MySQL select random rows with order by

Tags: mysql, random, sql-order-by

I want to retrieve random rows from table but this rows must be order in category.

```
select category, 
   (select order_number 
   from orders 
   where order_number in (123,125,128,129,256,263,966,258,264,159,786) 
   order by rand()) 
from orders 
order by category
```

This is the query I tried. But that retrieves whole data in table.

---

Worked query ;

```
SELECT category,order_number FROM (
    SELECT category,order_number 
    from orders 
    where order_number in (`$order_numbers_variable`) 
    order by rand()
) order by category
```

Comment: How many rows your want among all those numbers?

Comment: It's about 111 row. I mean there are 111 rows. `Order_number` field is unique. `Category` field is repeated. So I want to `order by category` in the same time select random `order_number`. That is like order in grouped field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the requirement is:
**Retrieve 'N' random rows from a table sorted by 'category'**.

Lets assume **N** is **10**. If you want to change the number of rows, then change it in the LIMIT clause.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT category from orders ORDER BY rand() ASC  LIMIT 10
) AS innerResult 
ORDER BY innerResult.category
```

Comment: @Yasin Yörük Please let know if this answer helps.

Comment: Thanks friend. Your query is help me to solve my problem. I changed something little in the query.